# How to package some classes of a project into a jar?

Tags: java, eclipse

Currently, I meet a problem. I need to do deserialize in ProjectB, and the serialized object is belongs to ProjectA. It means there hasn't ProjectA jar file in ProjectB.
My PM tell me that ProjectA is so large that I can't add ProjectA jar into ProjectB directly. He let me to fetch all the related classes from ProjectA and package them into a new jar. Then we add the new Jar file into ProjectB.
But I only know I need two classes but those two classes have many dependencies. So how to export all of them into a jar file?
Or do you have any other solutions to solve it besides add the hole ProjectA jar. Thank you.

Comment: One way is to decompose your big jar into several small ones so common component could be reused by other projects

Answer (score 0):

Use plug in projects. You can add dependencies  to other plugins and access the classes from dependent plugin.

More over modularize your classes based on the functionality. Do not put all your classes in one jar file which is not a good practice and you will realize it when your project grows bigger with lot of functionalities.

To answer your last question, there is no way eclipse can resolve your compilation errors. That's y we are here. The Programmers:-)

Comment: Thank you for your advise. Could you please provide some doc or the name of plugins? I am a newer in Maven. I haven searched Apache Maven to find this kind of plugin. I find maven-dependecy, is it Okay? Because I find it can't achieve my goal.

Comment: Maven will again take your project as it is and bundle it as a jar. It is helpful when you have continuous integration and such things. As far as I understand, you will have to modularize project A, move common classes to separate project C, add dependency to your project A and project B. Similarly create many small jars and give your manager.